# Selective printing of text block only there's a line match

Tags: regex, perl

I have a one-liner that prints lines in between two lines but I wanted to add another condition to only print the block if there's a line that matches *.pm:

```
perl -e 'while(<>){s/^/$ARGV:/; print if m#VLOG {Updated files}# .. m#VLOG {Priority}#;}'
```

Sample data:

```
VLOG {Updated files}
files/skel/usr/local/cp/Modules/vsap/config.pm
files/skel/usr/local/cp/Modules/vsap/files/list.pm
files/skel/usr/local/cp/lib/i386-linux-thread-multi/perllocal.pod
files/skel/usr/local/cp/templates/default/cp/files/dirdialog.xsl

VLOG {Removed files}

VLOG {Priority}
```

Any assistance is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{ $/ ="VLOG {Priority}$/" } s/^/$ARGV:/gm; print $1 if /^(VLOG {Updated files}.*?\.pm.*)/sm'
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to save the lines you might want to print, and print them at the end:

```
perl -e 'while(<>){s/^/$ARGV:/; push @save,$_ if m#VLOG {Updated files}# .. m#VLOG {Priority}#;} print @save;'
```

Now you want to look for lines that end in '.pm' and only print if you see one:

```
perl -e 'while(<>){s/^/$ARGV:/; do {push @save,$_; $sawPM = 1 if /\.pm/; } if m#VLOG {Updated files}# .. m#VLOG {Priority}#;} print @save if $sawPM;'
```